# Adding multiple joined objects at once in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

Let's say you have two objects to store in Redux, `A` and `B`, which are denormalized per the [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html), like this:

```
state = {
  a: { byId: { id: { obj } }, allIds: [] },
  b: { byId: { id: { obj } }, allIds: [] }
};
```

You have an action, `CREATE_A` which adds a new `A` to the store. **But, for every `A` created, it inherently needs a `B` as well**.  Assume that `A` and `B` are in separate reducer slices (i.e. `combineReducers`) and can't be merged into one.

It's easy to make `B`'s reducer react to the `CREATE_A` event and create a new `B`, but what if the `B` object needs the `A`'s ID that was just created?

Even if there's a [join table](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html#relationships-and-tables) involed to join `B` to `A`, there's still the problem of "knowing the `A` that was created first". The solution I came up with, was to store the last created `A` like so:

```
a: { lastCreated: {}, byId: etc, allIds: etc }
```

And then passing the whole state tree to either `B`'s reducer or the join table reducer, so it can access `state.a.lastCreated`. It doesn't feel right, though, to just have a key so that a *later* reducer knows what happened (the idea of reducers requiring a certain ordering also seems wrong)

I thought you could also dispatch a `CREATE_B` with the new `A`'s id, but that would have to be done in an async action (since you can't dispatch from a reducer), which also doesn't feel right.

In a procedural world, this would be trivial:

```
a = createA();
createB(a);
```

But even with two dispatches, I'm not sure how it would work:

```
dispatch( createA() )
dispatch( createB(???) )
```

What would be the best way to handle this case of "A-inherently-means-B-as-well"?

Edit: Let me try to use some more concrete examples.

Say you have `square`s and `point`s. Creating a `square` *inherently* means creating 4 `point`s. The points are joined with the square, because they form the square, but they also don't *belong* to the square, because they can be independent objects of their own right:

[image: square with points]

So, `ADD_SQUARE` needs to both add a square, and add 4 points, and then join the two together, and I'm not sure how to do this without writing a reducer directly in the parent "state" like this (I **don't** want to have to do this, it gets really messy really fast, imagine having to repeat for 3-8 sided polygons):

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(state) {
    case ADD_SQUARE:
        const points = create4Points();
        const square = createSquare();
        return {
            ...state,
            squares: {
                ...state.squares,
                byId: {
                    ...state.squares.byId
                    [square.id]: square
                }
            },
            points: {
                ...state.points,
                byId: {
                    ...state.points.byId,
                    [point[0].id]: point[0],
                    [point[1].id]: point[1],
                    [point[2].id]: point[2],
                    [point[3].id]: point[3]
                }
            },
            pointsSquares: {
                ...state.pointsSquares,
                byId: {
                    [square.id]: {
                        square: square.id,
                        points: [point1.id, point2.id, point3.id, point4.id]
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define the same action within both A and B reducers.. like so --

```
function reducerA(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case A_CREATE:
         do A stuff
  }
}


function reducerB(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case A_CREATE:
       do B stuff
  }
}
```

Then when you dispatch the action it will affect both reducers.

```
function createA({id, stuff, etc}) {
  return {
    type: "A_CREATE",
    payload: {id, stuff, etc}
  }
}
```

Then you can tie the id to whatever you need to create... thus "joining" them together.

EDIT:

You could use redux thunk or some other middleware like redux saga in conjunction with promises to dispatch multiple actions.

```
 `
  function handleACreation(payload) {
   dispatch(
      createA(payload)
       .then(result => dispatch(updateB(result)))
   )
  }
 `
```

obviously that exact code wouldn't work - but the general idea remains :] hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already doing that, see paragraph 3. `B`'s reducer still needs to know what `A` was created.

Comment: couldn't you just send this information into B's reducers through the action's payload?  In the action's payload you could send the id of the created A to B - and tie this id with whatever you create...

Comment: `A`'s ID is only known after an `A` has already been created. An `A_UPDATE` isn't the problem, it's `A_CREATE`.

Comment: have you looked into using redux thunk to handle side effects like this? You could instead dispatch an action in A_CREATE that would create an A and then (when this creation is done) dispatch another action to B's reducer https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk                          example:                                                                                                              dispatch(doThis())
.then(() => dispatch(doThat())

Comment: Talked about that in my question too. It doesn't feel right for something can _can_ be synchronous to be asynchronous. For example, if used with React, the first `dispatch` would cause a re-render of an intermediate "half-finished" state, which could cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this by creating `A`'s id in the *action creator* instead of in `A`'s reducer. For example,

```
function createSquare () {
    return {
        type: CREATE_SQUARE,
        id: newUuid()
    };
}

function squareReducer ( state, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
    case CREATE_SQUARE:
        return { id: action.id };
    }
}

function pointReducer ( state, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
    case CREATE_SQUARE:
        return [
            { id: newUuid(), square: action.id }
            { id: newUuid(), square: action.id } //etc
        ];
    }
}
```

I'm still open to other solutions though.